# How hover plot inputs over the plot itself in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, hover

In running the code at the bottom and as shown in this image, the four plot slider inputs rigidly appear at the top-left of the screen. Is there a way to make these four inputs instead hover over the plot, with the ability to drag/move, or hide, those inputs out of the way if they block the view of the plot? Of course they'd have to be shrunk etc. but that's OK. I'm open to any ideas! Trying to economize the visual impact of the presentation.

[image]

Code:

```
library(plotly)
library(purrr)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(6,
      sliderInput('periods','Nbr of periods:',min=0,max=24,value=12),
      sliderInput('start','Start value:',min=0,max=1,value=0.15),
      sliderInput('end','End value:',min=0,max=1,value=0.70),
      sliderInput('exponential','Exponential:',min=-100,max=100,value=50)
      ),
    column(3,tableOutput('data'))
    ),
  fluidRow(plotlyOutput('plot'))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  x <- reactive(data()$Periods)
  y <- reactive(data()$ScaledLog)
  
  data <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      Periods = c(0:input$periods),
      ScaledLog = c(
        (input$start-input$end) *
        (exp(-input$exponential/100*(0:input$periods))-
        exp(-input$exponential/100*input$periods)*(0:input$periods)/input$periods)) +
        input$end
    )
  })
  
  output$data <- renderTable(data())
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly(plot_ly(data(),x = ~x(), y = ~y(), type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
    layout(title = 'Scaled Logarithmic Curve', 
           plot_bgcolor = "#e5ecf6", 
           xaxis = list(title = 'Period'), 
           yaxis = list(title = 'Scaled Logarithmic Value')
           ) %>%
    config(edits = list(shapePosition = TRUE))  
  )
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check [shinyjqui::jqui_draggable](https://yang-tang.github.io/shinyjqui/), which we can combine with [shinyWidgets::dropdown](https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/reference/dropdown.html).

However, I'm not sure yet, why the `dropdown` itself is not draggable.

In addition we need to make sure to set a proper z-index for the `column`:

```
library(plotly)
library(purrr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    jqui_draggable(column(6, dropdown(sliderInput('periods','Nbr of periods:',min=0,max=24,value=12),
                                      sliderInput('start','Start value:',min=0,max=1,value=0.15),
                                      sliderInput('end','End value:',min=0,max=1,value=0.70),
                                      sliderInput('exponential','Exponential:',min=-100,max=100,value=50)),
                          style = "z-index:1; position: fixed; top: 5vh; left: 5vw;"
    ))
  ),
  fluidRow(plotlyOutput('plot')),
  fluidRow(column(12, DTOutput('data')))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  x <- reactive(data()$Periods)
  y <- reactive(data()$ScaledLog)
  
  data <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      Periods = c(0:input$periods),
      ScaledLog = c(
        (input$start-input$end) *
          (exp(-input$exponential/100*(0:input$periods))-
             exp(-input$exponential/100*input$periods)*(0:input$periods)/input$periods)) +
        input$end
    )
  })
  
  output$data <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      data(),
      filter = 'top',
      options = list(pageLength = 10, autoWidth = FALSE),
      rownames = FALSE
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({plot_ly(data(),x = ~x(), y = ~y(), type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
      layout(title = 'Scaled Logarithmic Curve', 
             plot_bgcolor = "#e5ecf6", 
             xaxis = list(title = 'Period'), 
             yaxis = list(title = 'Scaled Logarithmic Value')
      ) %>%
      config(edits = list(shapePosition = TRUE))  
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

[image: result]

Comment: @Victorp do you know why the dropdown itself is not draggable (only follows its contents)?

Comment: ismirsehregal, that is very, very nice! Beautiful. Maybe this is related to your question for @Victorp, I wonder if that little drop down can be placed on or just above the plot to economize on space. I'll fiddle around with that.

Comment: @CuriousJorge-user9788072 please see another edit and check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp). Cheers

Comment: @CuriousJorge-user9788072 btw. are you aware of `library(shinydashboardPlus)` and its right sidebar? It provides a nice structure to place inputs: [shinydashboardPlus::dashboardControlbar](https://rinterface.github.io/shinydashboardPlus/reference/controlbar.html) - please see the examples on the bottom of the page.

Comment: I know eventually I end up adopting shinyDashboardPlus